# Difference between \$r_d\$ and \$r_D\$ in diodes?

Tags: diodes, analog

I'd like to know what's the difference between \$r_d\$ and \$r_D\$ when regarding diodes.

I know that \$r_d\$ means dynamic resistance, but I'm not sure what \$r_D\$ means, and how it differs from the latter.

Comment: that will definitely be defined in whatever book you're reading, or you need a better book. In a datasheet, it's sometimes harder to tell, but often possible to deduct from other things. So, impossible to answer without you telling us where you found these symbols!

Comment: If it were defined in the source where I found those notations, then I'd already have my answer. I found the 'd' notation in a presentation sent to me and my peers in college, and the capital 'D' notation I found with no context in a class exercise.

Comment: Each good book or other knowledge source defines the symbols they are using. If you have something that does not give corresponding explanations - throw it away.

Comment: No context = no question.

Comment: Thing is, class exercises, according to my TA, don't need to have corresponding explanations, since they aren't a knowledge source - hence I am asking this question.

Comment: That's why your TA is still a TA.

Comment: The A is for assistant, so they're not the *primary* source of knowledge. Their sole job, however, is bringing you these sources closer. They should be telling you which material you've got to read when looking for where that came from. If they (or the professor) just copied and pasted some excercises from somewhere without copying the definitions – bad material. Get a good book.

Comment: If it was \$R_D\$ then I'd say "Static/DC resistance". I agree with others, btw.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but do none of you know the answer to my question, or you just don't want to answer? I'm asking because instead of saying I should get a better book, or that my TA isn't the best, which doesn't help me at all, you could have just answered or pointed me in the right direction in the first place.

Comment: @uriyaba `you could have just answered or pointed me in the right direction in the first place.` We just don't want to mislead you. If it wasn't defined/detailed in the source then how could we know it? In almost all the sources, \$R_D\$ is static/DC resistance and \$r_d\$ is AC/dynamic resistance. We could answer your question like "\$r_D\$ is static resistance" but it could be totally wrong.

Comment: @uriyaba There is no such thing that a symbol ALWAYS mean the same. That's why nobody gave you a direct answer. Just look at any moderately serious scientific publication. All the symbols are explained there. Yes, even r_d, V_T, V_
TH and V_GS, V_DS, etc. supposed to be defined in the text.

Answer (score 0):

the dynamic resistance will, for an abrupt junction diode, be 26 ohms/current(milliAmps). Thus reac (my term) is 26 ohms at 1mA, 260 ohms at 0.1 mA, etc. This equation also holds for bipolar transistors when you know the emitter (or collector) current. Simply scale up by the Beta, and you have the low-frequency Rin. (Miller Effect will eat up signal charge at high frequencies).

The Rd likely is the bulk resistance of the silicon, apart from the junction region (microns thick), and becomes apparent at "high currents", where the expected exponential behavior transitions into a "linear" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In some of my classes, there was a convention like this where DC-offset sine wave signals were concerned:

$$v_A = V_A + v_a$$

Where \$V_A\$ is the DC bias point and \$v_a\$ is the ac voltage (sine wave) with no offset. Then \$v_A\$ is the overall real signal.

I don't know if I ever saw the same for resistance, but it could be used the same way.

It's possible that the same convention is assumed in your assignment, but I would only rely on that if that's what you've been seeing in your books/lectures/examples.